# Javascript - Detect tags and check maxlength

Tags: javascript, html

I want to convert text in tags with dummy values in javascript's text field. Text field has maxlength of 20. As the user input some values, it will check whether it reaches maxlength of 20.

When user input the following:

```
This is value <VALUE_1>
```

It will replace  to dummy value, "12", and check if the following exceed maxlength of 20

```
This is value 12
```

I will use onkeyup to detect user's input as user input, but how should i do the detect tag, convert, and compare if it reaches maxlength 20?

Comment: you'll need to find tags, convert them and then check the converted string length ... javascript has regular expressions that will help the first part, replace function for the second part, and a string has a length property for the third part

Comment: thanks for your reply, it can only detect the whole VALUE_1 when user finishes the end tag >, how can i trace back to the starting tag < and get the whole VALUE_1 string?

Comment: trace what back? an `input` element value is the whole value, not just the last key pressed!

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```js
var textInput = document.getElementById("text");
var dummyInput = document.getElementById("dummy");
var resultSpan = document.getElementById("replaced");
text.addEventListener("keyup", function(e){
  var dummy = dummyInput.value;
  var text = textInput.value
  var result = text.replace("<VALUE_1>", dummy);
  if(result.length <= 20){
    resultSpan.innerText = result;
  } else {
    resultSpan.innerText = "too long!";
  }

});
```

```html
<label for="dummy">Dummy value:</label>
<input type="text" id="dummy" placeholder="Dummy value, e.g. 12" /><br />
<label for="text">Text to process:</label>
<input type="text" id="text" maxlength="20" placeholder="<VALUE_1> will be replaced by the dummy value in the result." /><br />
Replaced text: <span id="replaced"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you're looking for is simply some regexp.

```
"This is value <VALUE_1> <123>".replace(/<VALUE_1>/, mySecretSauce)
```

Where the value of `mySecretSauce` is 12.

You can also build the regexp expression dynamically like:

```
"This is value <VALUE_1> <123>".replace(new RegExp("<VALUE_1>"), mySecretSauce)
```